# Mapping multidimensional array from Mongo to Java application

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, jackson

I need to retrieve data from MongoDB. I am using Spring framework and MongoRepository. My problem is that the data is written to the DB by a different application as 2-element double array. This is the document as seen in MongoDB:

```
{    
    "options" : {
       "ampWavelength" : 3000,
       "continuumWindows" : [ 
           {
               "0" : 1140,
               "1" : 1150
           }, 
           {
               "0" : 1275,
               "1" : 1280
           }, 
           {
               "0" : 1320,
               "1" : 1330
           }]
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't retrieve the array with fields named "0" or "1". Is there any trick to it? So far I have tried creating "continuumWindows" object with fields named "_0" and "_1" or making a "double[][] continuumWindows" variable but neither has worked for me - I either retrieve 0, null or get an error.

Comment: I have the same result when using "@JsonProperty("0")". I retrieve 0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @Field annotation.
Example:

```
public class ContinuumWindow {

    @Field(value = "0")
    private int elementZero;

    @Field(value = "1")
    private int elementOne;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am just beginning to use Spring and forgot about this annotation.